# How do I check if a string is of a certain pattern without splitting it up?

Tags: java, regex

So this is the problem. Can someone tell me how a regex pattern might look like?

> Write a program that determines if the input string matches the following format:
>
> Format: `PRODUCT_ID.PRODUCT_CATEGORY-LOCATOR_TYPE[LOCATOR_LOT]`
>
> - `PRODUCT_ID` = always starts with # followed by 3 zeros, followed by a numeric value that can be 1-7 digits, in the range 1-9999999
> - `PRODUCT_CATEGORY` = 1-4 uppercase alphabetic characters
> - `LOCATOR_TYPE` = a single uppercase X, Y or Z character
> - `LOCATOR_LOT` = 1-2 numeric digits, in the range 1-99
>
> All other format characters are the literal characters
>
> Return true if it matches and false otherwise.

This is the function declaration:

```
public boolean checkPattern(String s){    
}
```

I tried splitting the string and then checking every character but it got very complicated.

Here's what I've got so far for a regex:

```
String regex = "#000^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$";
```

This is something I started with but its so long and complicated and not even complete (only checks the product id) that I dont think I am on the right track here

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you post your code attempt as a [mcve]? Thanks!

Comment: My other code is very lengthy. I basically split the string on '.' and '-' to check each substring separately. However, I don't pass some test cases because of this

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working regex:

```
#000[1-9]\d{0,6}\.[A-Z]{1,4}\-[XYZ]\[[1-9]\d?\]
```

And here's a breakdown:

```
#000    # match the literal characters, #000
[1-9]   # any digit 1 to 9 (to ensure there are no preceding zeroes)
\d      # any digit character; equivalent to [0-9]
{0,6}   # perform the preceding match (\d) anywhere from 0 to 6 times
        #    (0,6 instead of 1,7 because we already matched the first digit above)

\.      # match a dot character. Must be escaped with a backslash \ as
        #    the unescaped dot will match *anything* in regex otherwise.

[A-Z]   # any uppercase alphabetic character.
{1,4}   # will repeat the preceding match anywhere from 1 to 4 times.

\-      # match a hyphen character. escaping is optional here.

[XYZ]   # any of X, Y, or Z.

\[      # a literal [ character. Must be escaped.

[1-9]   # matches 1 to 9
\d      # any digit; equivalent to [0-9]
?       # Makes the preceding match optional. Equivalent to {0,1}

\]      # a literal ] character. Must be escaped.
```

---

**Other notes:**

A really nice tool that can help you understand regex better is the website [RegExr.com](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Works but doesn't follow some rules (like range of 1-9999999) - allows 0. Perhaps you should have `#000(?!0)\d{1,7}[A-Z]{1,4}[XYZ](?!0)\d{1,2}` or `#000(?:[1-9]\d{0,6})[A-Z]{1,4}[XYZ](?:[1-9]\d?)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I read up regex everywhere but just couldn't understand how to implement it and you cleared up. Here's one thing that bugged me though- for 3 (and consequently for 8), the number '0000000' will also be accepted but only the range 1 - 99999 is allowed. How do I deal with that?

Comment: @Anonhacer2397 see my comment (edited it to include two patterns that could be used)

Comment: My apologies didn't see that. Thank you for clearing this up for me!

Comment: Thanks, @ctwheels - I have just updated my answer to account for what you've pointed out.

Comment: @Anonhacer2397 can you explain what you mean about both of your questions here? Where is the illegal escape character coming from?

Comment: @Anonhacer2397 - my apologies, I reread your question. I initially did not realize you needed to match those characters as well. I've revised it yet again, to include those characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to determine the pattern of each element and then merge between them. I was able to identify every part but I did not understand the last one:

All other format characters are the literal characters.

Anyway, I hope this will help you out. Read the comments included in the code.

```
public boolean checkPattern(String s){

     if(s.matches("#000[1-9]{1,7}.[A-Z]{1,4}-([X-Z])\\[[1-9]{1,2}\\]")) return true;
          else return false; 

      // #000[1-9]{1,7} ==> matches PRODUCT_ID

      //. ==> to simply match the point

      // [A-Z]{1,4} ==> PRODUCT_CATEGORY

      //- ==> to simply match this symbol

      // ([X-Z]) ==> LOCATOR_TYPE

      // \\[ Use the double slash here so the [ symbol becomes recognized 

      // [1-9]{1,2} ==> LOCATOR_LOT

      // \\]

      //  String s="#000123.ABC-X[99]"; this is a test example I used.

}
```

While working with Regular expressions, you have to read well what is requested from you as well as the predefined regex operators and tools.

Comment: Thanks! But what happens if the numbers have the value '0'? That isn't permissible

Comment: You are right, I modified my solution. Thank you for your comment, I sometimes lose attention.

Comment: `(X|Y|Z)` - better to just use `[XYZ]` or `[X-Z]`.